# Polynomials over non-commutative rings

Tags: reference-request, polynomials

What would be a good source for polynomial expressions over non-commutative rings, such that the variable wouldn't have to commute with the coefficients, so that the substitution of a value from the underlying ring in place of the variable would be a ring homomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at Bourbaki's *Algèbre* VIII.1.4 (the new edition from 2012.)